# How to test the background of textview if it's right drawable set xml resource in Android Espresso in Kotlin programming language

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, instrumented-test

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin. I am adding instrumented tests to my application. I am having a problem testing the background of textview if it's right drawable set in XML resource.

I am setting the background of the text view programmatically like this.

```
when (type) {
            ApplicationController.EVENT_TYPE_FUTURE -> {
                detailsViewHolder.tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_future_event)
            }

            ApplicationController.EVENT_TYPE_PAST -> {
                detailsViewHolder.tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_past_event)
            }

            ApplicationController.EVENT_TYPE_CURRENT -> {
                detailsViewHolder.tvStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_current_event)
            }
        }
```

In the expresso, I want to assert that the text view is set with the right XML resource. How can I do that?

Comment: Kotlin espresso test case example : https://github.com/android/testing-samples/tree/master/ui/espresso

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the Espresso's view matchers [ViewMatchers.hasBackground](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers.html?hl=en#hasBackground(int)):

```
onView(withId(R.id.tvStatus)).check(matches(hasBackground(R.drawable.background_future_event)))
```

Although the matcher is in beta, but I hope it works in your case, otherwise you may have to create a custom matcher.